# How to remove sidebar in Shipping Address step Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7

I want to hide the sidebar in this **Shipping Address** Page on **Checkout**.

Note: I only want to hide the sidebar in **Shipping Address** step, not in other steps.

I did some **research** on it But found **Solution** for custom Step [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174206/remove-sidebar-in-checkout-custom-step-magento-2).

[image]

Please guide me to achieve a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174206/remove-sidebar-in-checkout-custom-step-magento-2 Check this out.

Comment: @bramulous Hi, I mentioned this link in the question. I tried it But it is for custom step not for shipping address step

Comment: How you have added edit button on address?any extension?

Comment: No. Its a default functionality but have to enable it js file

Comment: waw,can you give me file and line number? thanks

Comment: Go to this link and make return true in isEditable function https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module:

We need to use our custom component and template.

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/summary</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/summary</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (Component, quote, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isVisible: function () {
            return !quote.isVirtual() && stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
        }
    });
});
```

Our custom script should extend from the original summary script and we need to check the shipping step is processed or not.

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html**

```
<!-- ko if: isVisible() -->
    <div class="opc-block-summary" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Summary'" class="title"></span>
        <!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Try to clear your Magento cache and see the result.

Comment: Hi Khoa, Thanks for your Answer. I want remove entire sidebar and make it one column block without sidebar. But it was displaying like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ZTtXxTS.png)

Comment: Waiting me. I think we can do it easily.

Comment: Didn't Get you. Can you Suggest me how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: You can try this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157802/33057

Comment: But I want to remove sidebar only from Shipping address step. It was removing on Payment step also.

Comment: So, in this case, we need to try my answer above but we need to improve logic by yourself.

Comment: Okay. Will try, So I need to work around the xml file?

Comment: Yes, you should try with xml first.

Comment: Hi Khoa. Tried working on removing Side bar. Didn't get any hope to remove sidebar if I try to remove block it was removing in complete checkout Process. Please help me out of this. Thank you.

Comment: Seems that In your case, you shouldn' t remove the sidebar, just show and hide it.

Comment: Even if I was trying to hide block in JS file It was not showing up. I'm new to Knock out JS.

Comment: Did you try my answer or not? Does it work or not? One more thing, did you have any custom code in checkout page?

Comment: I Added `$('#checkout').addClass('custom-stepshipping');`  in summary.js . But it was not adding class to the Block.

Comment: No khoa. I didn’t have any custom code in checkout page. Your code hides order summary details. But not the entire sidebar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76146/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-raghav).

Comment: @Raghav let go to chat.

Comment: hi khoa. Sent you message in Chat. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add `<!-- ko if: isShow() -->` this line in your `summary.phtml` file**

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko if: isShow() -->

<div class="opc-block-summary" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Order Summary'" class="title"></span>
    <!-- ko foreach: elems() -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

After, call **`isShow() function`** and define **`Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator`** in your `summary.js` file

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'

], function (Component, totals, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
          isShow: function () {
       return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
    },

     isLoading: totals.isLoading

    });

});
```

Comment: @Raghav Please, try our solution and let us know is this working for you or not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Its not working. I want to remove complete sidebar and make shipping address block single column. Only in shipping address step not in payment step.